# In a metrizable space, the union of a chain of closed subsets of is F$_\sigma$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

> Let $(X,\tau)$ a metrizable topological space and $\mathcal{F}$ a collection of closed subsets of X which is linearly ordered by inclusion. Show that $\bigcup \mathcal{F}$ is F$_\sigma$.

**Here is my attempt to prove this:**

Let $d$ a metric that generates $\tau$. Suppose that is not possible to write $\bigcup\mathcal{F}$ as a countable union of closed sets, lets say $\bigcup F_n$, $F_n \in \mathcal{F}\enspace \forall n$.

Let $F\in\mathcal{F}$. If $K \in \mathcal{F}$, is such that $F\subset K$, there is $x \in K$ such that $d(x,F) >0$. So, it would be possible to obtain a non-countable set $\{x_K : K \in \mathcal{F} \}$ such that $d(x_K, F)$ is monotone increasing in $\mathbb{R}$. Then we obtain a non-countable collection of of disjoint open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$.

I am not sure if everything so far is right, and I don't have any other ideas to prove the assertion. Can anyone help?

Comment: Why would there be such an $x\in K$ ? And how do you know that the $x_K$ you pick are distinct ? (if $F\subset K\subset K'$, maybe $x_K= x_{K'}$ ). And there are uncountable increasing nets in $\mathbb{R}$, so you don't necessarily get disjoint intervals. I think you're going in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nate's observation is essentially this:
Let $X$ be a countably tight space, i.e. for every subset $A \subseteq X$

$$\forall x \in \overline{A} :\exists A' \subseteq A: (|A'| \le \aleph_0) \land (x \in \overline{A'})$$

Note that all metric spaces satisfy this, we can even take a convergent sequence from $A$ converging to $x$, using a countable local base.

Suppose $\mathscr{F}$ is a family of closed sets, linearly ordered by inclusion.

Suppose that $\mathscr{F}$ has an up-cofinal countable subset:

$$\exists \mathscr{F}' \subseteq \mathscr{F}: (\left|\mathscr{F}'\right| \le \aleph_0) \land (\forall F \in \mathscr{F} \exists F' \in \mathscr{F}': F \subseteq F')$$

In that case $\bigcup \mathscr{F} = \bigcup \mathscr{F'}$ (right to left inclusion is immediate and left to right inclusion folllows from cofinality) and the last set is an $F_\sigma$ by definition.

If there is no countable cofinal subset: $F= \cup \mathscr{F}$ is closed.

Let $x \in \overline{F}$, then the countable tightness guarantees that we have a countable subset $C$ of $F$ such that $x \in \overline{C}$. For every $c \in C$ pick $F_c \in \mathscr{F}$ with $c \in F_c$. Then $\mathscr{F}' = \{F_c:  \in C\}$ is countable so cannot be cofinal, which means that there is a $G \in \mathscr{F}$ such that for all $c$, $G \nsubseteq F_c$ and, as we have a linearly ordered collection, for this $G$ we have $F_c \subseteq G$.

Now: $$x \in \overline{C} \subseteq \overline{\bigcup\{ F_c: c \in C\} } \subseteq \overline{G} = G$$

as $G \in \mathscr{F}$ is closed. So $x \in F$ and so $F = \cup \mathscr{F}$ is closed ( so also an $F_\sigma$).

Comment: The second half:   Why didn't I think of that? ..:)

Comment: @user254665 It's a well-known type of argument, I had seen similar things before. It's often used in cardinal function arguments. Everything is trivial module experience

Comment: I've seen it often too. That's why I wondered why I didn't think of it for this Q.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think your proof works.  You can't ensure that, for $K \subset K'$, we have $d(x_K, F) \le d(x_{K'}, F)$.  Consider the chain $\{0\} < \{0,1\} < \{0, 1, 1/2\}$.   Also, even if you do get a monotone increasing chain in $\mathbb{R}$, that's no contradiction ($\mathbb{R}$ itself is such a chain) and it doesn't imply the existence of uncountably many disjoint intervals.

Here's a hint, though.  Set $A = \bigcup \mathcal{F}$.  If there is a sequence $F_1 \subset F_2 \subset \dots$ which is cofinal, i.e. such that for every $F \in \mathcal{F}$ there is $n$ such that $F \subseteq F_n$, then we are done because $A = \bigcup_n F_n$.  So suppose not.  In this case you can show that $A$ is closed.  For let $x$ be a limit point of $A$.  You can then find a sequence $x_n \in A$ converging to $x$.  But each $x_n$ is contained in some $F_n \in \mathcal{F}$; what can you do with the sequence $F_n$?

Comment: So the statement would hold in any sequential space (or space with countable tightness).